# staging beam sdk and suggestion of "pre-building workflow..." expected?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I run beam pipeline with the following on python3.8 and beam2.41.0rc1:

```
    argv = [
        "--runner", "DataflowRunner",
        "--experiments=use_runner_v2",
        "--sdk_container_image=us.gcr.io/some_beam_image_based_on_2.41.0rc1",
    ]
```

The beam image is built with bazel docker rules:

In `WORKSPACE`

```
# https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/beam_python3.8_sdk/tags
container_pull(
    name = "beam_python",
    # 2.41.0rc1
    digest = "sha256:0036b90ecfefddd1dd1614b9cd1ccec7c5a906ee2185542996bc26d6408d9e14",
    registry = "registry.hub.docker.com",
    repository = "apache/beam_python3.8_sdk",
)
```

In `BUILD`

```
cc_image(
    name = "sample_image",
    binary = ":sample",
)

container_layer(
    name = "sample_layer",
    tars = [":sample_image"],
)

container_image(
    name = "beam_sample_image",
    base = "@beam_python//image",
    layers = [":sample_layer"],
)
```

A custom apache-beam seems installed. Not sure if it is 2.41.0rc1.

```
root@3dc8fe29cd99:/# pip freeze 
absl-py==1.2.0
apache-beam @ file:///opt/apache/beam/tars/apache-beam.tar.gz
astunparse==1.6.3
atomicwrites==1.4.1
attrs==21.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
...
```

I saw the following log:

```
I0815 18:11:40.158377 140374774146880 stager.py:927] Downloading source distribution of the SDK from PyPi
I0815 18:11:40.158492 140374774146880 stager.py:934] Executing command: ['/home/swang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_swang/09eb83215bfa3a8425e4385b45dbf00d/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/garage/sample_launch.runfiles/python3_8_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpuqnjdrj3', 'apache-beam==2.41.0rc1', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/swang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_swang/09eb83215bfa3a8425e4385b45dbf00d/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/garage/sample_launch.runfiles/python3_8_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
I0815 18:11:42.881979 140374774146880 stager.py:825] Staging SDK sources from PyPI: dataflow_python_sdk.tar
I0815 18:11:42.883261 140374774146880 stager.py:900] Downloading binary distribution of the SDK from PyPi
I0815 18:11:42.883335 140374774146880 stager.py:934] Executing command: ['/home/swang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_swang/09eb83215bfa3a8425e4385b45dbf00d/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/garage/sample_launch.runfiles/python3_8_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpuqnjdrj3', 'apache-beam==2.41.0rc1', '--no-deps', '--only-binary', ':all:', '--python-version', '38', '--implementation', 'cp', '--abi', 'cp38', '--platform', 'manylinux1_x86_64']
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/swang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_swang/09eb83215bfa3a8425e4385b45dbf00d/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/garage/sample_launch.runfiles/python3_8_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
I0815 18:11:44.672350 140374774146880 stager.py:842] Staging binary distribution of the SDK from PyPI: apache_beam-2.41.0rc1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
I0815 18:11:44.675273 140374774146880 dataflow_runner.py:477] Pipeline has additional dependencies to be installed in SDK worker container, consider using the SDK container image pre-building workflow to avoid repetitive installations. Learn more on https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#prebuild
I0815 18:11:44.676919 140374774146880 environments.py:376] Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.41.0rc1
I0815 18:11:44.677026 140374774146880 environments.py:295] Using provided Python SDK container image: us.gcr.io/shawn-295406/beam_sample:20220815_test
I0815 18:11:44.677081 140374774146880 environments.py:302] Python SDK container image set to "us.gcr.io/shawn-295406/beam_sample:20220815_test" for Docker environment
I0815 18:11:44.723044 140374774146880 translations.py:714] ==================== <function pack_combiners at 0x7fab84d77820> ====================
I0815 18:11:44.723375 140374774146880 translations.py:714] ==================== <function sort_stages at 0x7fab84d78040> ====================
I0815 18:11:44.730723 140374774146880 apiclient.py:473] Defaulting to the temp_location as staging_location: gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp
I0815 18:11:44.750272 140374774146880 auth.py:136] Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds.
I0815 18:11:44.750348 140374774146880 auth.py:138] socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.
I0815 18:11:44.755919 140374774146880 apiclient.py:732] Starting GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/dataflow_python_sdk.tar...
I0815 18:11:45.899281 140374774146880 apiclient.py:748] Completed GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/dataflow_python_sdk.tar in 1 seconds.
I0815 18:11:45.899615 140374774146880 apiclient.py:732] Starting GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/apache_beam-2.41.0rc1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl...
I0815 18:11:48.883744 140374774146880 apiclient.py:748] Completed GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/apache_beam-2.41.0rc1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in 2 seconds.
I0815 18:11:48.884612 140374774146880 apiclient.py:732] Starting GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/pipeline.pb...
I0815 18:11:49.025467 140374774146880 apiclient.py:748] Completed GCS upload to gs://shizhiw/beam/tmp/beamapp-swang-0816011144-730582-ppdswudf.1660612304.730851/pipeline.pb in 0 seconds.
I0815 18:11:49.855348 140374774146880 apiclient.py:911] Create job: <Job
```

I'm a bit puzzled by the log:

1. beam is already installed both locally and in the container image, why does it seem to be downloaded again?
2. I'm already using custom container (base beam image + a cpp binary), why does the log still suggest me to use "pre-building workflow..."?

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apache-beam @ file:///opt/apache/beam/tars/apache-beam.tar.gz` basically says the Beam is installed from a tarball file on the container. It must be the `2.41.0rc1` pulled in as the base image in your Dockerfile or build system.

The info you are seeing is benign, see this [line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b30de9f163cf2e75963d5d57bba1d7f286a1f86f/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py#L476). It's logged whenever your pipeline options contain additional artifacts to retrieve. In your case, just the `sdk_container_image`.

Comment: Dataflow web UI seems to surface this as an insight now: "SDK worker container image pre-building: can be enabled", which according to the answer above seems like a false alarm. It would be great if such suggestions/insights can be more targeted.